# Grothendieck sites based on large categories?

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, grothendieck-topologies

A Grothendieck site is defined as a small category with certain structure. My question is: does it really have to be set-based? Are there notions of Grothendieck sites which are class-based? Would this cause trouble when considering the topos of sheaves?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It would cause trouble when considering $[C, Set]$, which would not be a category

Comment: Why is this? It wouldn't be class-based?

Comment: Its objects are classes themselves ( a functor $C\to Set$ is large). If you're looking at it in terms of Grothendieck universes for instance, for two large subsets $A,B\subset \mathcal{U}$, $B^A$ will not necessarily be $\subset \mathcal{U}$